# Send api request every x minutes and update context with status

Tags: python, django, ajax, web, background

I am trying to make a website, where user can start a task on a button click, which will send an api request every x seconds/minutes. Api request gets a list of offers as a response and the task will check if the api request is the same as before.

If it is then then i want to show status on my page as: "No offers were found, still searching" and if the api response is different the status changes to: "I found an offer"

I wanted to make that process in the background and without need to refresh the page by user. I want the context["status"] to be automatically updated when new offer is found.

I tried to achieve this with threading but the page keep on loading as a task is working.

Every idea is appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Although you can use Ajax, I prefer to use websocket and, therefore, channels. Have a look to this tutorial: https://realpython.com/getting-started-with-django-channels/ or https://blog.logrocket.com/django-channels-and-websockets/. There are lots of tutorials on the web and also book like Django 3 by example (disclosed: I am not the author). Besides, channels is an official Django project and, it will be part of Django in the coming release.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'll check that in a moment.

Answer (score 0):

create a custom result view in django, set a timer on your page and then use [jQuery.load()](https://api.jquery.com/load/)

```
var l_timer = setInterval(function(){
    $( "#result" ).load( "/my_periodic_view", function() {
       alert( "Load was performed." );
    });
},1000) //1000ms loop
```

you will require jquery. The better approach is to use ajax calls and rest api(or a socket depending on particular case), but both require additional setup on the server, and if your application does not need more realtime updates, going for the load approach is cheap easy and straightforward.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!